What to say when I'm so excited about a book and read it at crazy speed: "read the book voraciously"?
Searching for the expression online, I've found many examples of the phrase read voraciously, but very few of read the book/novel voraciously.
So, is read the book voraciously natural? If not, what should I say when I'm so excited about a book and read it at crazy speed?

Voracious means greedy. It does seem to be used to refer to reading lots of books rather than reading one quickly - but a similar metaphor is devour a book, which certainly is used.

One can't read everything, but if a particular genre, topic or author gains your attention, reading voraciously means you read everything relevant that you can get your hands on. It doesn't have to mean you are a fast reader, though, only that you saturate yourself.

"voracious reader" is a hackneyed expression, so to say "I read it voraciously" would be understood to mean you gobbled it up; you didn't read a few pages or a chapter and think about it for a while before reading further. For you, the book was a "page-turner".

One thing you can say is

I couldn't put the book down.

Cambridge Dictionary has

not put something down
idiom
If you cannot put a book down, you are unable to stop reading it until you reach the end:
It was so exciting from the first page I couldn't put it down.


Summary: this seems reasonable, but you might make small changes.
Looking up define voracious, I do find "having a very eager approach to an activity: 'his voracious reading of literature'" and "excessively eager : INSATIABLE : a voracious reader". I agree with @KateBunting that, even if these entries don't acknowledge it, I understand "voracious reader" as emphasizing that you read a lot of books, but of course you have to be fast to get through a lot, and these definitions do talk about reading eagerly and quickly. I would argue that the usage you're proposing is perfectly reasonable.
But it's funny how we use words in certain patterns. It's way more common to say that someone "is a voracious reader" than that they "read voraciously." It feels a little odd since it's a less common usage, and I might pick a different wording. Especially if you normally read more slowly, and just got excited about one specific book, you might avoid this word that's normally used to describe a personal trait. Kate's suggestion of "devour" is a great one since it comes from the same Latin root as "voracious" anyway.
